# How to retrieve type of device starting from its public ip

Tags: network

Given a public ip, is there a way to retrieve what's lying behind?

I mean if I use ***nmap -PO 159.149.xx.xxx*** I am able to know if the device is alive (responding to ping) and which ports are open.

But basically I don't know if it's a switch or a machine (computer running Windows) having a public ip.

Any help will be highly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: -O enables OS fingerprinting, and --osscan-guess tells nmap to guess what the OS is even if it doesn't find a perfect match.

Comment: thanks but if for example through -PO you get Host is up (0.00064s latency).
Not shown: 997 closed ports
PORT     STATE    SERVICE
53/tcp   filtered domain
2000/tcp open     cisco-sccp
8291/tcp open     unknown Can you say the device is probably not a computer?

Comment: You will likely find your answer here: http://nmap.org/book/osdetect-usage.html

Answer (score 2):

Apart from nmap, try to telnet the ports yourself. Some servers provide headers, like SSH does (this is how nmap identifies the ports):

```
root@debian:~# telnet 193.231.X.Y 22
Trying 193.231.X.Y...
Connected to 193.231.X.Y.
Escape character is '^]'.
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.5p1 Debian-6+squeeze5
^]
telnet> cl
Connection closed.
root@debian:~#
```

You can see the SSH being run on a **Debian** server above.

Web servers usually react to couple of CL+LF, but ifnot, you can issue a GET request:

```
root@debian:~# telnet localhost 80
Trying ::1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.




GET / HTTP/1.0

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 10 Feb 2015 11:44:04 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.16 (Debian)
Last-Modified: Thu, 30 Oct 2014 20:09:38 GMT
ETag: "c357-b1-506a975bb4480"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 177
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html

<html><body><h1>It works!</h1>
<p>This is the default web page for this server.</p>
<p>The web server software is running but no content has been added, yet.</p>
</body></html>
Connection closed by foreign host.
root@debian:~#
```

Same **Debian** here. You can see the space before the GET request, I've tried couple of new lines.

Remember, this applies to services that do not default to their usual port (like SSH on some ABCD port, or a web server on ABCD port. Also these are examples for known services, you might however bump into headers of some other service. So first use nmap to find open ports, then check them manually if nmap doesn't know them - some wording might represent an useful piece of information for a human than for nmap.

One more thing: use more flags and extend the search on all ports, using various nmap options, i.e. (careful if you're crossing third party networks as they might not like your port scanning):

```
nmap -p1-65535 -sV --version-all -sU -sN --reason -T5  193.231.X.Y
```

And, if you have access on some host on the same LAN/VLAN, look in the ARP Cache table and check the MAC OUI (first three bytes of the mac address), then look it up on the net, getting the vendor name ([Wireshark provides an OUI Lookup Tool](https://www.wireshark.org/tools/oui-lookup.html)). Usualy some PC/Server NIC is not manufactured in the same plant asa a switch (there are exceptions, take HP for example, but not Cisco or Juniper, they don't manufacture PCs or Servers).

Answer (score -1):

Since you are on the wanman portion of the transaction, you're not likely to get more information from the machines located behind the ip address. Banner retrieval will get you what is public facing, but to peer into the lan portion is not trivially possible.

Comment: The OP isn't asking to know what devices are behind the IP, but wanting to know more about the device itself.